# Is there a way in TFS to identify any PBIs or Features with missing acceptance criteria, Descriptions, Attachments?

Tags: tfs

Any team who works in sprints need a properly documented PBIs and Features. There might be times, when these PBIs or features are not well documented.

Is there any way in TFS to find out all PBIs, Features who have any one or more of following missing?

1. Description
2. Acceptance Criteria
3. Attachments

Also are there any tools to test if PBI is well written or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could go to project->Boards->Query page and add these filters to get the results:
[image]

Then you will be able to get Features or Product Backlog Items with empty Description, Acceptance Criteria or Attachments.

And for your reference, if what you want is much higher quality query then the issue description, you could consider the [Wiql Editor extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.wiql-editor).

In this issue you could also use the extension to write to get your wanted result:

```
SELECT
        [System.Id],
        [System.WorkItemType],
        [System.Title],
        [System.State],
        [System.AreaPath],
        [System.IterationPath]
FROM workitems
WHERE
    [System.TeamProject] = @project
    AND [System.WorkItemType] IN ('Product Backlog Item', 'Feature')
    AND [System.Description] IS EMPTY
OR
    [System.TeamProject] = @project
    AND [System.WorkItemType] IN ('Product Backlog Item', 'Feature')
    AND [Acceptance Criteria] IS EMPTY
OR
    [System.TeamProject] = @project
    AND [System.WorkItemType] IN ('Product Backlog Item', 'Feature')
    AND [System.AttachedFileCount] = 0
ORDER BY [System.ChangedDate] DESC
```

and run the query you could get something like this:
[image]

I hope this could do some help.